# Is it possible to pass the reference of a Mutex into a new thread? Do we always need to use move for the closure?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Say I wanted to pass the reference to a Mutex inside new threads, would that be possible?

Example:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let counter = Mutex::new(0);
    let mut handles = vec![];

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let handle = thread::spawn( || {
            let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();

            *num += 1;
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a reference into a thread, or at least a `std::thread::spawn` thread.

A thread needs to be able to live for `'static` because for all it knows it will end up being the last thread and the borrow checker could not possibly work across thread boundaries to make sure that the `Mutex` you're referencing is still allocated.

Thus, `Arc`. It's not dropped while someone's still holding it, so there is no worry of valid borrows.

Comment: Also consider using [Weak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) with `Arc`